# Why does English have so few "obscene" roots, compared to Russian?

Tags: history, formality, offensive-language, word-formation

Russian has 4 obscene roots (*'-**еб**-'*, *'-хуй-'*, *'-пизд-'*, *'-бляд-'*) and a huge variety of options in order to create new words:

> *'**еб**ать'*, *'**ёб**аный'*, *'у**еб**ать'*, *'за**еб**ать'*, *'подъ**еб**ать'*, *'**еб**антяй'*, *'у**ёб**ок'*, *'у**ёб**ище'*, *'съ**еб**ать'*, *'при**еб**ать'*, *'вы**еб**ать'*, *'за**еб**атый'*, *'**еб**учий'*, *'**еб**анутый'*, *'отъ**еб**аться'*, *'на**еб**алово'* etc.

And that's just using  one of the above!

English has, as far as I can tell, one obscene root ('-fuck-') and not many possibilities to word-formate. 'Fucked'. 'Fucking'. Maybe you can make something like 'overfucked' or 'upfuckery'. Nevertheless, this is not even around a heap of options that Russian has.

I have done NO "research", but I did find some information about this issue that Russia was baptized much later than Europe, so while obscene words were banned by the Church, obscene language in the west had very little opportunity to develop and rise. On the other hand, Russian obscene language had had hundreds of years before it was "outlawed". But still, do you think that five hundred years or so makes that big a difference? Maybe there are  more substantial reasons to be so?

P.S.: It is NOT a joke, or trolling, or something. I'm really interested in this area. Look at this exclusively from a scientific standpoint. Like a composed doctor examining some vagina sores or something

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55045/discussion-on-question-by-sergey-zolotarev-why-does-english-have-so-few-obscene).

Comment: Unfortunately,  I think the only person qualified to answer this question would be someone who is bilingual and has a high level of mastery of both English and Russian obscene vocabulary. Without input from someone like that, it's not even possible to come to an agreement on the premises. As terdon's answer and many comments indicate, English speakers who don't speak Russian can't understand what you mean: we don't think of our language as only having one obscene root. It may be relevant that Russian and English have different tendencies about word-formation in general.

Answer (score 7):

I don't really see any way of answering this short of giving you a list of other obscene and/or vulgar words. So here are a few (this list is far from comprehensive) and examples of a compound word you can create (or which already exists) using them:

- *fuck* : *fuckwit*
- *cunt* : *cuntrag*
- *shit* : *shithead*
- *ass* : *asswipe*, *asshole*
- *dick* : *dickhead*
- *cock* : *cocksucker*
- *pussy* : *pussywhipped*

The last compound word isn't exactly a vulgar insult, but it is a compound built from an offensive word.

Not all of the above are equally offensive, of course, but none are words I would use in a formal setting or even, with the possible exception of *dick* and its derivatives which are less offensive than the others (as are some, but not all, derivatives of *ass*) in any but the most unofficial registers (so only when chatting with close friends, for example).

Other words that you can use to craft vulgar insults include:

*Prick*, *balls*, *wank*, *toss*, *twat*, *eejit*, *bugger*. . .

The list is very, very long. These are just the obvious ones I could come up with off the top of my head.

So no, it is absolutely not true that English only has one vulgar root. It has many more than that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55044/discussion-on-answer-by-terdon-why-does-english-have-so-few-obscene-roots-com).